# Adding subview to UITableViewController that covers only the bottom half of the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'd like to achieve the following look, when clicking on the email envelope button a UIViewController that has custom size to fit width of screen and half the height of screen will "fly up" from button and cover some rows until it's closed.

so if this is the UITableView[image]

after click on email envelope it will look like this
[image]

Comment: take a view(bottom view) and set its y coordinate to go beyond the screen. Now on envelope button click, animate this out of screen view, into the screen as per your required y coordinate.

Comment: @z22 your idea works, but adding the view to the tableview , like you wrote  its added to the bottom, now the problem is that when scrolling down in the uitableviewcontroller it doesn't stop at the last cell and keeps going down (length of the added view) I've tried to set the contentSize of the tableview but it didn't help - how can i limit the scrolling of the uitableview ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a simple `UIViewController` which adopts `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` for your custom `UITableView` instead of the build in `UITableViewController`. So you have a simple `UIView` as main view container (not a `UITableView`). On this `UIView` you can add any view you want, including an [animated View](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:completion:) which is drawn above your table.

Comment: this cannot work with static tables it works only with dynamic